# Error in php Database connection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm getting the error: No database selected
Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database_name = "Student"; 

    mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
    mysql_select_db($database_name);
    ?>
```

This code is for php-connect.php class and for the form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <?php
    //load database connection
    include("php-connect.php");
    $id = "1";
    $name = "Elena";
    $city = "Lahore";

    //Command to insert into table
    $query = "INSERT INTO studentdata (id,name,city) VALUES ('$id','$name','$city')"; 

    //run the query to insert the person.
    $result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error()); 

    //let them know the person has been added.
    echo "Data successfully inserted into the database table ... ";
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the code for the form.. I've tried a lot of things to fix this error but it does not work. Is there any problem with my database?

Comment: Print `mysql_error()` after the _connect.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. Please use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Perhaps selecting the database didn't work out? (Use `mysql_error()` there also)

Comment: I used mysql_error() after selecting now the error is "Unknown database 'student'"

Comment: *""Unknown database 'student'""* - So create it or rename it, if it's called `Student`

Comment: By the way... `Student` and `student` are **two different animals** altogether. `$database_name = "Student";` --- change it to `$database_name = "student";` then.

Comment: ^------ Notice the uppercase `S` and lowercase `s`?

Comment: YEa I've tried that already :(

Comment: Did you in fact create the `table`? Not just the database. Database is `Students` with uppercase `S` and table is `studentdata` right?

Comment: yes Ive created the table..

Comment: And your `studentdata` table itself, the table's name doesn't contain a space by any chance? And all 3 columns exists?

Comment: Try `include_once("php-connect.php");` or `require_once("php-connect.php");` see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes it does not contain any space, and have all three columns as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database_name = "Student"; 

$mLink = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database_name , $mLink);
```

**another file**

```
<?php

require 'php-connect.php';


//...... etc..
```

but, read this first:

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>   mysqli_select_db() 
>   PDO::__construct() (part of dsn)

http://br.php.net/mysql_select_db